Flask user authentication including login, register and google login not integrated together
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-setup-user-authentication-in-flask/
I have made the basic user authentication using the above link but i am unable to add the google login.
I have tried many times but i am unable to add google login.
Can anyone help me making this ??
problem is there are src_init_.py and manage.py(this is outside src)
so i don't know how to add google login

Please elaborate on what you have done, what didn't work and what you expect to happen. This is not a useful question.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
